Window sill issues, barrier under window
I noticed that a few of my window sills were letting condensation underneath so I decided to pull them up.
After looking at a few of them, it seems like so far 3 have this odd window barrier tape underneath. The issue is this is damp and seems to be soaking up the condensation like a wet paper towel.
Is this normal? Is there anything I should do to prevent it from seeping into the house and ruining the window sill boards?
https://imgur.com/a/iKOzDhP
